# Compute a rotation relative to ENU

Tags: coordinate-system, cesium, rotate, globe, heading

I am using CESIUM JS. I posted a message in cesium forum some days ago, but I didn't manage to find a solution.

I have a 3D camera moving freely on a map.
I have a 2D map (let's call it minimap) that show a flat representation of the current location.

In the Minimap, I would like to represent the rotation (only heading since it's 2D) of the camera.

[image]

Now, since the 2d MAP always point to the globe north, and the camera is free to rotate in all the direction, I need to represent the rotation of the camera relative to East North Up coordinate (ENU) to use the correct heading for the minimap.

Cesium provide a lot of tools https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Transforms.html?classFilter=Transform#.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame

and I tried to use them, but it's really confusing and I don't quite get exactly how it works.

I tried for exemple

```
// get a fixed frame (matrix4) at my current position with the correct ENU
matrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(camera.position)
// use the matrix 4 to get heading pitch roll at the current fixed frame
headpitchroll = Cesium.Transforms.fixedFrameToHeadingPitchRoll(matrix)
// substract current north to the camera rotation
heading = camera.heading - headpitchroll.heading
```

But is not displaying the correct rotation.

Should I do something similar to this ?

get a fixed frame with no rotation of the current ENU
apply the camera rotation in this frame
get the heading of that rotation in that frame